# Dynamic cron job using quartz+spring

Tags: java, spring, cron, quartz-scheduler

I want to schedule a cron-job using quartz+spring.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hotelscrapper" /> <!--hotelServiceImpl-->
<bean id="ScheduleScrapJob" class="com.hotelscrapper.util.ScheduleScrapJob">
<property name="hotelService" ref="hotelServiceImpl">
</property>
</bean>

public class ScheduleScrapJob extends QuartzJobBean {
private HotelService hotelService;
public void setHotelService(HotelService hotelService){
    this.hotelService = hotelService;
}   
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    hotelService.reScrapWorker();
}

}
```

**hotelService is null**. I do not understand how i can link hotelService to service **hotelServiceImpl**.

**Solution:** hotelService is to be static. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you using component scanning, you must add the necessary annotations to your classes:

```
@Component
public class ScheduleScrapJob extends QuartzJobBean {
  @Autowired
  private HotelService hotelService;

  @Override
  protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    hotelService.reScrapWorker();
  }
```

}

With this setup, you will not need the hotel service setter in the ScheduleScrapJob class and your xml configuration will simply be:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.hotelscrapper" />
```

This assumes all the classes you need scanned are in the package tree under com.hotelscrapper.

Comment: I have used <context:component-scan base-package="com.hotelscrapper" /> for hotelServiceImpl

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal Ah you are using component scanning. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define something like this:

```
<bean id="hotelServiceImpl" class="com.hotelscrapper.HotelServiceImpl">
  <!-- some properties here -->
</bean>
```

As you did `ref="hotelServiceImpl"` in the `ScheduleScrapJob` bean definition, Spring will take this other `hotelServiceImpl` bean and set it into your `ScheduleScrapJob` bean, particularly into its `hotelService` property.